# Filtering Data Returning Same Data In Firestore Query

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React Native project using firebase. I have a screen that creates filters and then passes it to the Home Screen as params. I want to call a function every time the filters change, however, I am getting the same result in the console even though I change the filters.

### Edit

In theory in the `console.log(error)` I should be redirected to a composite index however, this isn't happening? - adding Firestore as a tag to the question.

Okay so I've added the query manually adding the where parameters manually and I seem to get a link directing me to create an index. I'm still not sure why this is though.

**Checklist**

- I have checked the filters are being updated in the params
- I have checked the updated filters are being passed to the query

### Here is my code in Home.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (filters) {
    console.log("FILTERS CHANGED:", filters); // filters get updated here
    fetchFilteredData();
  }
}, [filters]);

const fetchFilteredData = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await getFilteredData(filters, city);
    console.log(data.venues); // getting same data despite filters changing
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}, [filters, city]);
```

### Here is my code in firestore.js

```
export async function getFilteredData(filters, city_id) {
  console.log("FILTERS IN GET FILTERED DATA:", filters); // filters got updated here too ????
  let venues = [];
  let lastVenue;
  let query = firestore().collection("venues").where("city_id", "==", city_id);
  if (filters.districts.length > 0) {
    query.where("district_id", "in", filters.districts);
  }
  if (filters.category) {
    query.where("category_id", "==", filters.category);
  }
  if (filters.order) {
    query.orderBy(order, "desc");
  } else {
    query.orderBy("created_at", "desc");
  }
  await query
    .limit(20)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      lastVenue = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        venues.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
    });
  return { venues, lastVenue };
}
```

### Filters Object

```
{"category": "22DrTJ7hnEiZ8igZk4zS", "districts": [], "order": null}
```

### Edit

I've noticed that my orderBy should contain filters.order not just order, this hasn't effected my problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the variable `filters` contains?

Comment: @james I've update in the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Query` object in Firestore is immutable. When you call `where` or `orderBy` on a `Query`, it doesn't modify the existing query that you call it on, but rather it returns a new query.

That means that all of these operations accomplish nothing:

```
if (filters.districts.length > 0) {
  query.where("district_id", "in", filters.districts);
}
if (filters.category) {
  query.where("category_id", "==", filters.category);
}
if (filters.order) {
  query.orderBy(order, "desc");
} else {
  query.orderBy("created_at", "desc");
}
```

Each of these returns a new query with the new condition/ordering, but your code doesn't capture the new query.

To fix this:

```
if (filters.districts.length > 0) {
  query = query.where("district_id", "in", filters.districts);
}
if (filters.category) {
  query = query.where("category_id", "==", filters.category);
}
if (filters.order) {
  query = query.orderBy(order, "desc");
} else {
  query = query.orderBy("created_at", "desc");
}
```